# insert data from a wp_usermeta table

Tags: mysql, sql-insert

How can I **insert data** from below **wp_usermeta** into an company table when the wp_usermeta has all the data in 3 columns:

Structure of wp_usermeta is: ID - user_id - meta_key - meta_value

> Below  user_id + meta_key + meta_value must insert into table company

```
meta_key = 'gender' -> gender
meta_key = 'first_name' -> first_name
meta_key = 'last_name'  -> last_name
meta_key = 'street_address' -> address
meta_key = 'zipcode' -> zipcode
meta_key = 'city' -> city
meta_key = 'country' -> country
meta_key = 'telephone' -> company_phone
```

Have no idea how to solve this.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `wp_usermeta` (
  `umeta_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `meta_key` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `meta_value` longtext,
  PRIMARY KEY (`umeta_id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
  KEY `meta_key` (`meta_key`(191))
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=6026 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `wp_agent_companion` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(15) NOT NULL,
  `commerce_number` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `vat_number` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `company_name` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `gender` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(12) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(34) NOT NULL,
  `service` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `address` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `zipcode` varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,
  `city` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `country` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `company_phone` varchar(24) DEFAULT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=93 ;
```

Comment: Can you share the definitions of the `wp_usermeta` and `company` tables please?

Comment: I have add it in the thread, see above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this big query makes your desire table temporary?

```
INSERT INTO wp_agent_companion
(user_id, gender,
 first_name, last_name, address, zipcode,
 city, country, company_phone)
SELECT
    t1.user_id as user_id, 
    t1.meta_value as gender,
    t2.meta_value as first_name,
    t3.meta_value as last_name,
    t4.meta_value as address,
    t5.meta_value as zipcode,
    t6.meta_value as city,
    t7.meta_value as country,
    t8.meta_value as company_phone
 FROM
  (SELECT * FROM wp_usermeta) as t1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM wp_usermeta) as t2
ON t2.user_id = t1.user_id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM wp_usermeta) as t3
ON t3.user_id = t1.user_id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM wp_usermeta) as t4
ON t4.user_id = t1.user_id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM wp_usermeta) as t5
ON t5.user_id = t1.user_id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM wp_usermeta) as t6
ON t6.user_id = t1.user_id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM wp_usermeta) as t7
ON t7.user_id = t1.user_id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM wp_usermeta) as t8
ON t8.user_id = t1.user_id
WHERE
    t1.meta_key = 'gender' AND
    t2.meta_key = 'first_name' AND
    t3.meta_key = 'last_name' AND
    t4.meta_key = 'street_address' AND
    t5.meta_key = 'zipcode' AND
    t6.meta_key = 'city' AND
    t7.meta_key = 'country' AND
    t8.meta_key = 'telephone'
```

Just you're able to insert them to `company` table with `INSERT INTO SELECT (..)` that would be known for you.

> ```
> INSERT [LOW_PRIORITY | HIGH_PRIORITY] [IGNORE]
>     [INTO] tbl_name
>     [PARTITION (partition_name,...)]
>     [(col_name,...)]
>     SELECT ...
>     [ ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE col_name=expr, ... ]
> ```
>
> About [INSERT SELECT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html)

Comment: Yes, Thanks. Very quick.

Comment: I get a list of all data but do not understand the insert into select ()

Comment: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Comment: Because of some fields in `wp_agent_companion` table that did not exists in select query, we should add field name after `INSERT INTO tablename`. Code updated. @Hermants

Comment: Sorry get this:  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'null as id ,t1.user_id as user_id, gender, first_name, last_name, address, zip' at line 2. I think here is the problem:     t1.user_id as user_id, 
    t1.meta_key as gender,
Double t1 use. I will test it tomorrow again. Have to leave. Thanks anyway

Comment: `t1.user_id as user_id` in field names was mistake!! I've removed `t1.user_id as ` to fix it. try again @Hermants

Comment: nope again error:  to use near 'null as id , user_id, gender, first_name, last_name, address, zipcode, city,' at line 2

Comment: still strugle but i have to leave now.

Comment: There? Will be online at 18:00 GMT (amsterdam) Result now after update are fieldnames instead of data:1251  NULL NULL NULL g  first_name  last_name  NULL street_address  zipcode  city  country  telephone

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137277/discussion-between-mohamad-and-hermants).